# Spinner populated with Firebase information does not show selected item

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, spinner

### Disclaimer

I did a lot of research before making this question, and I know that there is a lot of questions like this with some answers, but none of them solved my problem, so I am making this question as an act of despair.

### Context

I'm populating a spinner with an array list populated with information from Firebase database.

### The problem

The spinner show the information when I click on it, but does not show the selected icon.

### The code

**Getting the information:**

```
public static List<String> getStudentsList() {
    final List<String> studentsList = new ArrayList<>();
    studentsList.add("");

    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Students");
    reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot studentSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String studentName = studentSnapshot.getValue(Student.class).getStudentName();
                studentsList.add(studentName);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    return studentsList;
}
```

**Setting the spinner:**

```
private void setUpStudentSpinner() {
    List<String> studentsList = FirebaseUtils.getStudentsList();

    ArrayAdapter<String> studentAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, studentsList);
    studentAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    Spinner studentSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerLessonStudent);
    studentSpinner.setAdapter(studentAdapter);
}
```

And I call the method setUpStudentSpinner() on onCreate().

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: I also had the same problem. solved it by moving the adapter creation and set on onDataChange like described in the answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/39234757/7765487